# How do I Google a range of numbers in a link?

Tags: google-search

How do I Google - which books on [Toronto Public Library's website fitting my selected criteria](http://www.torontopubliclibrary.ca/search.jsp?Erp=50&N=37918+37751+37861+20206+37844&No=150&Ntt=law), have 50-100 copies?

[Inputting](https://www.google.com/search?ei=1AhcWrrZIMuWjwPw26i4CQ&q=50..100+copies+site%3Atorontopubliclibrary.ca%2Fsearch.jsp%3FNtt%3Dintroduction%2Bto%2Blaw%2Bin%2Bcanada&oq=50..100+copies+site%3Atorontopubliclibrary.ca%2Fsearch.jsp%3FNtt%3Dintroduction%2Bto%2Blaw%2Bin%2Bcanada&gs_l=psy-ab.3...977988.980909.0.981127.2.2.0.0.0.0.926.926.6-1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.0.0....0.0RPVz1Lf1mQ)

`50..100 copies site:torontopubliclibrary.ca/search.jsp?Ntt=introduction+to+law+in+canada`

got me nothing. But this is clearly wrong because it missed [this book](http://www.torontopubliclibrary.ca/detail.jsp?Entt=RDM3539552&R=3539552) with 89 copies.

Comment: Are you sure that the missing book is properly indexed by Google?

Answer (score 1):

Please bear in mind that Google can only return as results pages that are indexed and in order to make some search operators work properly, those pages should be properly indexed to use them.

If you aren't sure if the missing book is properly indexed you should contact the library webmaster.